# Why do cut-off points in Ordered Probit/Logit not precisely determine predicted outcomes given the fixed component of an observation?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, ordinal-data

I am estimating an Ordered Probit model with three independent variables and five possible outcomes. The outcomes are categorical and ordered in nature. In my understanding, the cut-off points that are estimated together with the fixed effects determine how the linear / fixed part of the model maps onto the outcome space. When predicting observations not observed in estimating the model, I find this not to be the case and was wondering if this behaviour is correct.

Given an observation with observed values of my three independent variables which was excluded from estimation, I always assumed I could simply calculate the fixed effects as $X\beta$ and evaluate between which cut-off points this fixed part lies to obtain a prediction. However, when I actually use a prediction routine I find unexpectedly that these cut-off points don't exactly determine the mapping. I understand that you in fact calculate probabilities for each outcome whether the observation lies within it, but I would nonetheless expect the cut-off points to define the most likely category given a fixed component. Instead, I find that for fixed parts close to the cut-off points, it frequently occurs that the 'predicted' category is in fact on the other side of the cut-off.

Below I illustrate this behaviour in R where I plot the fixed component on the x-axis together with the cut-off points estimated by the model. On the y-axis I illustrate the built-in prediction by the model. As you can see, the two do not coincide, implying that the cut-off points do not distinguish the exact mapping of the fixed component onto the most likely outcome.

```
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(10000, 1, 5)
x2 <- rnorm(10000, 2, 5)
x3 <- rnorm(10000, 3, 5)
y <- 0.1*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.3*x3 + rnorm(10000, 0, 1)

y_cat <- ifelse(y < -1, "1",
                ifelse(y < 0, "2",
                       ifelse(y < 1, "3",
                              ifelse(y < 3, "4", "5"))))

df <- data.frame(outcome = as.factor(y_cat), x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x3 = x3)
train_df <- df[1:7500, ]
test_df <- df[7501:10000, ]

fit <- MASS::polr(outcome ~ x1 + x2 + x3, method = "probit", data = train_df)
summary(fit)

y_hat <- as.matrix(test_df[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")]) %*% fit$coefficients
y_hat_cat <- ifelse(y_hat < fit$zeta[1], 1,
                    ifelse(y_hat < fit$zeta[2], 2,
                       ifelse(y_hat < fit$zeta[3], 3,
                                  ifelse(y_hat < fit$zeta[4], 4, 5))))

ap_op <- data.frame(predict_mod = predict(fit, test_df), predict_fixed = y_hat) %>%
  mutate(correct = ifelse(predict(fit, test_df) == as.factor(y_hat_cat), "Correct", "Wrong"))

ggplot(ap_op, aes(x = predict_fixed, y = predict_mod,  color = correct)) +
  geom_jitter() + geom_vline(xintercept = fit$zeta)
```

[image: Example]

To make this more concrete, the 837st observation of the test set contains the following values: $x_1 = 2.396, x_2 = -0.331, x3 = 2.380$ which would imply a fixed part of $2.396 * 0.1007 + -0.331* 0.195 + 2.380* 2.98 = 0.886$ which would lie between cut-off points 2|3 and 3|4 according to my naive approach and thus should be assigned category 3. When running the built-in prediction routine, the observation gets assigned category 4. See below for an example and the estimated model coefficients:

```
Call:
MASS::polr(formula = outcome ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = train_df, 
    method = "probit")

Coefficients:
    Value Std. Error t value
x1 0.1007   0.002908   34.62
x2 0.1950   0.003476   56.10
x3 0.2982   0.004227   70.56

Intercepts:
    Value    Std. Error t value 
1|2  -1.0420   0.0269   -38.7779
2|3  -0.0062   0.0225    -0.2753
3|4   0.9770   0.0242    40.3920
4|5   2.9943   0.0393    76.1366

Residual Deviance: 13819.09 
AIC: 13833.09 

as.matrix(test_df[837, c("x1", "x2", "x3")]) %*% fit$coefficients  # 0.8865
predict(fit, test_df[837, ])  # 4
```

Comment: It's good to keep in check the desire for point predictions that don't contain their own uncertainties.  Ordinal regression based on cumulative probabilities (often called cumulative probability models) such as the probit ordinal model you are using invite you to compute $P(Y \leq y | X)$ and from those compute $P(Y = y | X)$.  You can also compute means (if Y is interval scaled) and modes from the model.  The use of the mode is risky if the probability that Y = the mode is not very large.

Comment: Agreed! I'm just amazed that the above seems to imply that $P(c_{k-1} < Y \leq c_{k}|X)$ is not always largest when $\hat{Y} \in [c_{k-1}, c_{k}]$ with $c_{k-1}, c_{k}$ two cutoff points and $\hat{Y}$ the fixed component for some observation..! Based on the above I gather $P(c_{k-2} < Y \leq c_{k-1}$) can in fact be larger even if $Y \in [c_{k-1}, c_{k}]$ which seems counter-intuitive to me...